# What must I do to redirect to a Web Form from an MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports, webforms, crystal-reports-2010

I have this line in my controller:

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebForms/ReportViewer.aspx");
```

Then this simple test code in `Page_Load` of "ReportViewer.aspx":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello");
    return;
}
```

This code does not even execute, i.e. `Page_Load` does not execute. I suppose there is something I'm supposed to do before redirecting to a web form, but have no idea what it is. I have seen ample sample code that just plainly calls `Redirect`.

My web form does have a Crystal Reports viewer on it, which may have something to do with the situation:

```
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return Redirect("~/Webform.aspx");
```

is perfect and its return type is RedirectResult and it works awesome, I have tested it.

My Action look like this

```
    public ActionResult Print()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Webform2.aspx");
    }
```

Thanks to @Andrey Gubal

Answer (score 1):

May be this link will be helpful: [Response.Redirect to another url](http://forums.asp.net/t/1536724.aspx/1) This is simular question about redirection from controller to .aspx

The main idea is to use `return Redirect("url");`instead `Response.Redirect("url");`

Comment: That doesn't compile. The return type of `Redirect` is void.